# Connecting github repository with my webpage

Tags: github, github-pages

Hey how to connect my webpage with github repository ,I mean , when I merge  pull request  it immediately make change in my webpage.I was using github-pages but now I would like include some php and it doesn't work. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Manual**: after each push to the repo you´d have to pull on your server for the current version. (You don´t want this...)

**Automation**: first you need a server (linux/ windows) with git installed and clone the repository to your webserver directory (i.e. apache.webserver: var/www/html). Then you need a script which automaticly pulls the new changes to your server and use a [webhook](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/) to trigger the script. That way you´d have the current version of your repo on the server all the time. (Push --> Webhook triggers script --> Server repo get´s new changes)

**Alternative**: create NOT a github BUT a git repository hosted on your own server ([tuturial for linux only](https://www.kennwilson.com/notes/2013/08/self-hosted-remote-git-repositories/)). You could push into it aswell and you´d have the current version of your site on the server without the path over github.

Comment: Thanks a lot , that is exactly what I was looking for :)